# Where to put User ID in a GA tracking flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I am using [React-GA](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga), and it works as expected, but I have a requirement to put user email in event tracking:

I see this in the example:

```
ReactGA.event({
  category: 'Editing',
  action: 'Deleted Component',
  label: 'Game Widget'
});
```

I have a email of each user as a string. Where do I better put it in the request?

Answer (score 10):

yes i am with @davids answer but i want to give more proper answer.

first you need to import `react-ga4` module

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4';
```

and than whenever you initialize google analytics you can set `userId` there

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01', {
  gaOptions: {
    userId: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
  }
});
```

Or if you want to set `userId` after user logs into your system, than you can do the following way

**1. initialize google analytics without `userId`**

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01');
```

**2. and just after login you can set `userId`**

```
ReactGA.set({ userId: 123 });
```

ref: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#reactgasetfieldsobject

To unset the `userId` when the user logs out or when you no longer wish to track the user under a specific ID, you can update the `userId` to `undefined`. This removes the `userId` association in your Google Analytics data, stopping the session from being linked to the previously set user ID.

```
ReactGA.set({ userId: undefined });
```

ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAnalytics/comments/14m4rds/ga4_how_to_unset_user_id_and_user_properties/?rdt=49671

Answer (score 5):

You should not use an email address as that is personally identifiable information and as such to track it in GA is against Google's terms and conditions.

Comment: Not only is it not secure and against the ToS for Analytics, if you try to set email address as the userId it will identify this and then not accept it at all. Something like a `username` field, something unique but doesn't identify the person, should work better.

Comment: @TylerRussell where can i get more information about this

Comment: @JoeLaw where can i get more information about this

Answer (score 2):

User ID ("userId") should be setup in the "initialize" or "set" GA command, not in an event. User ID is scoped to the user, so it shouldn't ever change for a user. Also, you'll have convert email to an anonymous (non-PII) id before it's used as userId

ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01', {
  debug: true,
  titleCase: false,
  gaOptions: {
    userId: 123
  }
});

User ID doc: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId